# Set a minimum salary for job offers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Just received an email from SO:

> **We really like this job for you.**
>
> Software Developer
>
> *****
>
> €40,000 - €65,000    Visa Sponsor   Paid Relocation

Is there any way I can specify that such offers are below my salary expectations, without switching off all job offers?

**== EDIT ==**

To clarify: I have no job alerts configured.

Comment: Yes it's possible, see dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Are job emails based on user searches?

Comment: @BSMP no, job emails are by-request only, you have to actually subscribe to get them, and choose what keywords you want. SO never sends such emails without request.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this particular email isn't a job alert; you get it when subscribed to the 'Tips & Recommendations' email bucket and it uses match preferences to try and find jobs that we think the user will be interested in. I'll bring up the salary filter idea with the team, seems like that's a valid request for the job we highlight as being the best match for the user.

Comment: @DeanWard huh. So maybe reopen this and post what you said as answer? :)

Comment: This should remain closed as the functionality available in the job alerts is also available (and effective) in the general job search field.